# Improve indexing to speed up slow query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE TIME_FORMAT(ADDTIME(journey.departure
        , SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(link2.elapsed))), '%H:%i') AS departure
FROM journey
JOIN journey_day 
    ON journey_day.journey = journey.code
JOIN pattern 
    ON pattern.code = journey.pattern
JOIN service 
    ON service.code = pattern.service
JOIN link 
    ON link.section = pattern.section 
   AND link.stop = "370023591"
JOIN link link2 
    ON link2.section = pattern.section 
   AND link2.id <= link.id
WHERE journey_day.day = 6
GROUP BY journey.id
ORDER BY journey.departure
```

The above query takes 1-2 seconds to run. I need to reduce this to roughly 100ms. Please note that I understand the `service` table hasn't been used in the query, but that is just to simplify the question.

[image]

Any ideas how I can speed this up? I can see that the link table is using filesort, is this causing the slowness in the query?

Comment: `INNER JOIN link ON link.section = pattern.section AND link.stop = "370023591"
INNER JOIN link link2 ON link2.section = pattern.section AND link2.id <= link.id` --- what this part exactly means? It looks strange that a table is joined to itself then IDs are compared. It generates a cartesian product doesn't it? Is it a reason you use `GROUP BY` further?

Comment: @zerkms This is actually to do with calculating a bus timetable, so the JOIN gets the ID of the link in that section, and then the second join returns all the rows before it so we can calculate the total time it takes for the journey to get to that stop

Comment: You are joining to `link` twice, making it `O(n*n)`. It can't be fast.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov it's not `O(n^2)` "It can't be fast" --- this is based on... what? There are 50 and 16 rows selected correspondingly. Selecting 800 rows in total is slow? Are you serious?

Comment: Convert secondo join to link table with exists subquery

Comment: @zerkms, please correct me if I'm wrong. What does the `rows` column that shows numbers `16` and `50` mean? Is it the number of rows that matched the search condition? Is it the number of rows that the server looked through, i.e. number of rows in the table? I thought it is the number of matching rows. To find these 16 rows the server may had to look through 100M of rows if the table is big. `O(n*n)` is because the server joins the `link` to itself on `link2.id <= link.id`. OK, it is `O(n*n/2)`, which is still `O(n*n)`. Did I get it wrong?

Comment: "is because the server joins the link to itself " --- what is the complexity of search over B-Tree? Why do you think it's `O(N)`?

Comment: @JoeTaras Could you please write an answer with an example? If it works I will upboat and select as answer

Comment: @zerkms, it is not just one search in the tree. it is a `join`. and `join` not on equality comparison`(=)`, but on `(<=)`. My point is that it very unlikely to increase the speed of this query as it is by 10-20 times (from 1-2 seconds to 100ms) by simply adding indexes. We can see that there are indexes there already. It may help a bit to have one more index on `link` `(section, stop)` or `(stop, section)`, depending on the distribution of values. But I would not expect it to change speed dramatically.

Comment: @Vladimir Baranov `ON link2.section = pattern.section` --- oh god, please have a look on the EXPLAIN and the query once again, carefully this time. "But I would not expect it to change speed dramatically" --- it is **ALREADY THERE**.

Comment: @user3605739 any chance all the tables are innodb? Is `link.id` a primary key?

Comment: @zerkms, is there a composite index on two columns there? I'm not sure, that I interpret results of `EXPLAIN` correctly. I suggested to add a composite index (if it is not there already). @user3605739, it would be interesting to know your final results, if anyone answers with any good ideas. Please post eventually what you tried and if anything helped to speed the query.

Comment: @Vladimir Baranov: even if it's not composite (it does not matter much) - it's an index over `section` that is a straight equality comparison followed by a scan over just 50 (fifty) rows.

Comment: @zerkms Yes and yes, all are innodb and link.id is primary key

Comment: Good, so now it's even a clustered index, so `id` is in the index already. No reason to make it composite @VladimirBaranov And, no, there is no reason to have a composite index for both `section` and `stop` at all - the `link` table is selected first so the `link.section = pattern.section` predicate is not used for the filtering from it (it's used for joining a `pattern` table).

Comment: Still no further than I was two hours ago :-(

Comment: The correct way to go about it is to put an ANALYZE in front of the query, and ask your query planner what it's doing, and try to figure out why that's so slow.

Comment: Just add a composite index on link(stop, section), and check the speed and examine the explain after that.

Comment: @kordiko Should I remove the separate indexes on stop and section?

Comment: I don't know - if these indexes are used by other queries, deleting them may affect these quesries. You can examine which indexes are unused and then safetely delete them, see this link for details: http://www.percona.com/blog/2012/06/30/find-unused-indexes/

Comment: @kordirko `link(stop, section)` is redundant, I have already mentioned it above in the comments.

Comment: Try changing the joined order of the tables to put journey_day first, ie `... FROM journey_day JOIN journey ON ...`. Theoretically, it shouldn't make a difference, but I've seen this work - putting the table with the where clause condition first.

Answer (score 0):

One thought is that you could explicitly optimize the selection of the "link" table record with minimum "id" value.

Using a temporary table or materialized WITH statement are two approaches that would work to produce the result set.  Two approaches to get the minimum value of "id" are 1) ordering by id, adding a row_number and selecting the first value; or 2) I use a windowed row_number, ordering by id, and again select the row with value 1.

Answer (score 0):

Well planned indexes can by crucial to performance.  From what you have presented, I would start with the following specific indexes... these are all covering indexes to qualify all the joins and criteria you will be working with.  Covering indexes help the engine because the engine can get all the data that qualify without having to go to the raw data pages.

Most specifically, starting with your journey table, I would explicitly have the composite index based on all 3 fields in the order I have them...  Day first as that is your WHERE criteria, then ID as that is the GROUP BY and finally DEPARTURE for your ORDER BY clause.

The LINK table based on section and stop first as those are the criteria as joined to the journey table.  ID next as it is basis of joining to LINK2, and finally ELAPSED for your field criteria selection.

```
table    index
journey  (day, id, departure)
link     (section, stop, id, elapsed)
pattern  (code, service, section)
service  (code)
```